# java script code notworking

Tags: javascript, html, css

hello my javascript code is not working i included the css and the script in the code i don't have good experience in javascript maybe there is something missing i need some help here thanks in advance

```
  <html>

<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
  "use strict";

  $("button").click(function () {
    $(".popup").fadeIn();
  });

  $("span").click(function () {
    $(".popup").fadeOut()
  });


});
</script>
<h1>Hello world ! </h1>
<button>click</button>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="overlay"> sheko </div>
  <div class="box">
      <span>X</span>
  <div>
</div>

</body>
<head>

<style>
.popup{
   z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
.overlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.90);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box span{
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: put the function at the bottom. Or wrap it in a on document ready

Comment: how to do that please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working already.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.popup{
   z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
.overlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.90);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box span{
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
  </head>
  
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
  "use strict";

  $("button").click(function () {
    $(".popup").fadeIn();
  });

  $("span").click(function () {
    $(".popup").fadeOut()
  });


});
  
</script>
  

<h1>Hello world ! </h1>
<button>click</button>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="overlay"> sheko </div>
  <div class="box">
      <span>X</span>
  <div>
</div>

</body>





</html>
```

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

The order of your HTML is totally incorrect, you have the `<head></head>` tag below the `<body></body>`.

Place the head tag above the body, just after the opening html tag then move your css and the link to jQuery in this section.

Finally it's better to add your JS at the very bottom of the page as the browser reads the dom from top to bottom, thus will increase the speed of the page load.

```
  <html>

<head>

<style>
.popup{
   z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
.overlay{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.90);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.box{
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #FFF;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box span{
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Hello world ! </h1>
<button>click</button>
<div class="popup">
  <div class="overlay"> sheko </div>
  <div class="box">
      <span>X</span>
  <div>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
  "use strict";

  $("button").click(function () {
    $(".popup").fadeIn();
  });

  $("span").click(function () {
    $(".popup").fadeOut()
  });


});
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.

First the css in `<style></style>` tag **must** be in your `<head></head>` of your page.

Best solution is using external css file and add him with a `<link>` in your `<head>`.

After that the `<script>` section is highly better on the bottom of your page because the browser compile in order of your code.

If you want add `<script>` before html add your script in this function :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

write the jS code in a .js file and use

```
<script src="foo/bar/yourScript.js"></script>
```

the style sheet in an .css and use a

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bar/yourStyle.css">
```

so the Script-tag is always at the Bottom of the body-element
the head is above the body and the link-tag inside the head

Answer (score 0):

Here is suggestion that please maintain the flow of code.
    write the css Style in head tag and jquery or JavaScript after body tag completed.

```
Here is jsfiddle link

https://jsfiddle.net/nbcakhzz/2/

Hope it will help you.
```